# Vagrant + Chef + Hostname

Tags: vagrant, chef-infra

I am pretty new using Vagrant and Chef. I am trying to change the Hostname of my Vagrant image using Chef. For some reason, I do not see a changed Hostname when I do `vagrant ssh`

What am I missing?

Here is my `Cheffile`

```
site "http://community.opscode.com/api/v1"

cookbook 'apt'
cookbook 'build-essential'
cookbook 'hostname'
```

Here is my `Vagrant`file

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  # Use Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty Tahr 64-bit as our operating system
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"

  # Configurate the virtual machine to use 2GB of RAM
  config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
    vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", "2048"]
  end

  # Forward the Rails server default port to the host
  # config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 3000, host: 3000

  # Use Chef Solo to provision our virtual machine
  config.vm.provision :chef_solo do |chef|
    chef.cookbooks_path = ["cookbooks", "site-cookbooks"]

    chef.add_recipe "apt"
    chef.add_recipe "hostname"

    # Install Ruby 2.1.2 and Bundler
    # Set an empty root password for MySQL to make things simple
    chef.json = {
      hostname: {
        set_fqdn: 'Olympus'
      }
    }
  end
end
```

Comment: Did you run `vagrant provision`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As defined in the documentation you should set the attribute at the node level, not in node['hostname'].

In your case it will be

```
chef.json = {
  set_fqdn: 'Olympus'
}
```

You can find more information in [The hostname documentation](https://supermarket.getchef.com/cookbooks/hostname)